# Determining font family names from a TTF file

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am adding custom fonts support in my framework where user will provide a ttf font file.
I am able to use custom font files as follows.

Note that i have also provided the font name ("Agency FB").
how can i get font family names inside the ttf file?

```
        Uri uri = new Uri ("/Fonts;component/Test.TTF", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        FontSource fs = new FontSource(info.Stream);

        PageTitle.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Agency FB");
        PageTitle.FontSource = new FontSource (info.Stream);
        PageTitle.FontSize = 72;
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but can you use `GetTextFace` function?
I would try selecting the font and then then getting its face name using the API.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911447.aspx

Comment: this function is for 6.5, am looking for wp7

Comment: oh... sorry, didn't realise that.

Answer (score 0):

```
FontFamily font = new FontFamily("Digitaldream.ttf#Digital Dream");
```

Build Action:
Embedded Resource